# TIdTCPClient Android not connecting to TIdTCPServer on local PC

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, indy

Using Rad Studio (Delphi) 10.3.2, I have a TCPServer app on my local PC and created an app running on an Android phone to connect using the local IP address, but I get "Connect timed out".  Both are connected to the same local network via 192.168.1.x range addresses.  I can ping the phone device from my PC.  I can connect to the TCPServer from another Windows PC on the network, so that's working.

I don't understand what could be getting in the way. Is there something in Android preventing connections to a local IP address?  I have the Android Manifest for my app allowing INTERNET access but not sure if there is another one for accessing the local network.

I also tried connecting from the phones Chrome browser but nothing arrives at all at the TCP Server.

Comment: A firewall on your PC can prevent it. Switch it off for a test. Test with the Chrome browser first.

Comment: I already had an exception for the app in the firewall, but switched it off anyway for Domain and Private connections but still nothing.

Comment: Switch off the firewall completely during test.

Comment: I would try using telnet to connect to the ip:port. The protocol is wrong (obviously) but Telnet will at least tell if it connects or not.

Comment: Ok, just tried that and doesn't work. I used another old Android phone Samsung Galaxy S5 and it works, so it appears to be a fault in the OnePlus 7 phone. Perhaps the Chinese manufacturer has disabled access to local IP addresses on purpose or accidentally.

Comment: Maybe there's a setting on that phone that will enable local ip connect?

Comment: I thought of that but can't see any obvious setting.  If it was an option, I can't imagine why anyone would ever want to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was caused by the 1.1.1.1 DNS app that I had installed on the phone.  Disable that and then local IP connections are possible.